# C realloc() on a Flexible Length Array

Tags: c, realloc

I have the struct along with these functions on it. The purpose is to mimic a list storage/access using a preallocated array.

```
#define ALLOC_INC_COUNT 100

typedef struct
{
  size_t count, el_size, alloc_count;
  char data[];
} bl_t;

bl_t *bl_new(size_t el_size)
{
  bl_t *list = malloc(sizeof *list + ALLOC_INC_COUNT * el_size);

  if (list == NULL)
    return NULL;

  list->count = 0;
  list->el_size = el_size;
  list->alloc_count = ALLOC_INC_COUNT;
  return list;
}
```

My question is if I want to resize the struct using a function like bl_add(), the program functions incorrectly on the memcpy line in those cases after the struct has been reallocated. I'm not quite understanding why.

```
bool bl_add(bl_t *list, void *data)
{
  if (list->count > list->alloc_count - 1)
  {
    bl_t *swap = realloc(list, sizeof *swap + (list->count + ALLOC_INC_COUNT) * list->el_size);

    if (swap == NULL)
      return 0;

    list = swap;
    list->alloc_count += ALLOC_INC_COUNT;
  }

  memcpy(list->data + list->count * list->el_size, data, list->el_size);
  list->count++;
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: How exactly does the program "function incorrectly"? Can you show the problem with a short [mre]?

Comment: The program segfaults on the memcpy line after realloc() is called.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `bl_add` can reallocate the `bl_t*` it is passed as an argument, but it has no way to inform its caller that it has done so, or what the new value of the argument should be. So the caller's `list` becomes a dangling pointer, and the next time it uses it, chaos (aka Undefined Behaviour) will ensue.

One solution is to return the new value of `list` (or `NULL` in the case of failure), requiring the caller to write:

```
 list = bl_add(list, data);
```

Another possibility is to ask the caller to pass a *pointer* to the `list` pointer (a "handle"), allowing `bl_add` to update the pointer:

```
 status = bl_add(&list, data);
```

Comment: Indeed both would work. In the second case I have to keep track of the original source of the list pointer which is something I wish to avoid.

Comment: So when I do list = swap, does the pointer as an argument not get updated?? I always thought it would.

Comment: @OS2: No, function arguments in C are always pass by value.

Comment: @os2: I prefer the first solution myself, but I don't quite understand your critique of the second one. I like the first solution because it can be chained (`list = bl_add(bl_add(list, data1), data2)`. Many people don't like that style. (Shrug!) To do that, I would add `if (!list) return list;` at the beginning of `bl_add`, so that allocation errors can be passed through the chain.

Comment: @ Nate Eldredge, yes indeed the pointer itself is pass by value.

Comment: @rici, Actually both solutions are one and the same thing. These are correct solutions and make the program work properly but I always ran into problems carrying the pointer forwards using the & of a *. Hence I was looking for a looking for simpler solution to push a single pointer but was at a loss to understand why it did not work. Thank you.